# update session variable in yii

Tags: php, session, yii

I want to know how can i update my session variable, 
in my controller, when i am on page1, 
in my **public function actionpage1()**
i have this code

```
$quantity=1;
$sessionCart[] = array('product_id' => $_POST['documents'], 'document' => $productInfo->name, quantity'=> $quantity);
```

so my default quantity is 1,

And when i go to another page page2, and click on update button,

I want my $quantity to be equal to $_post['quantity'] my new valule, 
(this is `<?php echo CHtml::textField('quantity', $value['quantity']); ?>`)

Comment: The answer can be read in the Yii documentation for CHttpSession http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession

Answer (score 3):

You can store session data with:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('key', 'value');
```

and get it with:

```
Yii::app()->user->getState('key');
```

Comment: Please note that this info will be stored on the user object. So if the user is logged in, and he/she logs off, all session data set by the CWebUser will be gone. Would be nice to note here so the OP knows what the consequences are.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:-

```
Yii::app()->session['name'] = $value
```

Answer (score 1):

in your form field:

```
CHtml::textField('quantity', $value['quantity']);
```

the value must be retrieved from session array variable but not from the passed static variable:
Replace value like this:

```
CHtml::textField('quantity', sessionCart['quantity']);
```