# Update the value in the session after submiting the form using YII framework

Tags: php, session, yii

I really need big help for this.
I have a form, and in that form client can choose country, and document type, and there is add to cart button.

So when the client select everything he need, all parametars are send into the session like this (this is in controller):

```
$quantity = 1; //this is default quantity for all documents
if(isset($_POST['cartBtn']))  {

        if(!isset(Yii::app()->session['cart_values'])) {
            Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] = array();
        }

        $sessionCart = Yii::app()->session['cart_values'];
        $productInfo = Product::model()->find('id=:id',(array(':id'=>$_POST['documents'])));

            $sessionCart[] = array('product_id' => $_POST['documents'], 'document' => $productInfo->name, 'countries'=>$_POST['countries'], 'quantity'=> $quantity, 'price' => $unitCost);

            Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] = $sessionCart;

        $this->redirect(array($this->id."/cart"));

    }
```

after submiting the form the client is redirected to cart form, here in this form he can update the quantity of documents.
Now i have to determinate which column did the client select to update.

I try to do this in controller (under cart action) :

```
public function actionCart()
{
    if(isset($_POST['cartBtnUpdate'])) {
        $sessionCart['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
    }
    $this->render('cart');
}
```

but when i do this nothing happened the value is 1, i enter 2 or 3 submit the form but value is 1.

Also I would like to delete the field if someone click the check box and submit the form, but i have no clue how to select the all session line to delete it.

Thanks.

---

Form code in cart view:

```
<?php
    if (is_array(Yii::app()->session['cart_values']))
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ( Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] as $value) {

            $total += $value['price'];

    ?>

<tr id="TDcartTable">
    <td class="docName">
      <?php echo $value['document'] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        £ <?php echo number_format($value['price'], 2); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
       <?php echo CHtml::textField('quantity', $value['quantity']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        £ <?php echo number_format(($value['price'] * $value['quantity']), 2);
        ?>
    </td>
          <?php }
}
?>
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="column-last" colspan="6">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cart-order-total" colspan="6">
        <?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::t('app', 'Order Total')); ?>: £ <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="cartBtnUpdate" value="<?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::t('app', 'Update Your Shopping Cart')); ?>">
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="cartBtnContinue" value="<?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::t('app', 'Continue')); ?>">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is the third time you've asked this question. Glad to see you've included more detail this time. If the answers aren't what you require you should improve the question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: yes, i'm sorry for that, i just don't get the answer, and i am afraid that no one will seen my question. I really don't get this update session thing, and i start to feel bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value with same name in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062859/value-with-same-name-in-array) - do not duplicate your own questions - ***NEVER EVER*** - instead edit the previous one to improve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [update session variable in yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105660/update-session-variable-in-yii)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$sessionCart` is not defined in your controller action before you attempt to use it. You need to define it:

```
if (isset($_POST['cartBtnUpdate'])) {
    $sessionCart = Yii::app()->session['cart_values'];
    $sessionCart['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
}
```

Comment: I define it, but still on submit the form nothing happened.

Comment: @5ome: First of all `['cart_values']` is an array of arrays: `$sessionCart[] = array(...)` so `$sessionCart['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];` will have no effect because it's writing data to the wrong place. Second, the cart has many items -- which quantity are you supposed to be modifying? You probably need something like `CHtml::textField('quantity['.$value['product_id'.']', ...)` and also need to fix all the other code to use these ids as keys.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I try to fix it now.

Comment: @Jon: OP is a mass-self-duplicator. I won't even consider to answer nor care. And as it stands: Your answer can not be helpful at all (as all the other answers to this users session update questions (four or so) were. So technically -1 because this is not helpufl.

Comment: @hakre: Thanks for the heads up, I rarely check OP history and in this kind of sideline questions it's not very common for someone else to point it out. I CVed.

Comment: Well, please consider to sharpen your senses, right now those low quality questions are really exploding and like with this user, it can be a mess. Sorry for the technical downvote, I guess you're rep-couch is still comfortable :)

Comment: @hakre: No worries about voting, rep is nice but it's silly to argue about it, it's just bits on a server. I agree with you in general, but IMHO containing these low-q questions is kind of a lost cause. Masses of people that want to have their problem solved generate a force too strong to resist even with all the mod tools in the world. It's like going against human nature.

Comment: Or well, maybe it's against the rep-system, right. I still think there is use of linking dupes etc..

Comment: @hakre: Of course it's useful. I 'm just saying that we can hope to limit the damage from the tsunami a little, but not prevent it.